# What are the differences between -Wall and -Weverything?

Tags: g++, clang++

I was assuming that they are the same flags for different compilers, but, it seems to me there are differences more than that. Just I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-Wall turns on a lot of useful warnings and depending on your style and sense of perfection you'll find the compiler nagging at you. Solving these will improve code quality and solve bugs before they have the opportunity to be found.

-Weverything warns about pretty much every single little thing you could find. Even some things that are perfectly fine according to the C++ language. This is more useful in an IDE setting than it helps you when compiling code.

Comment: No, it's a clang thing